# How to get many2one for same calendar instance in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

The following code is calendar.event inherited module so here I will store some inspection and all. Here relation is working fine.

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api

class calendar_event(osv.osv):

    _inherit = "calendar.event"

    STATE_SELECTION = [
        ('1', 'Corrective'),
        ('2', 'Preventive'),
        ('3', 'Predictive'),
        ]
    SD_SELECTION = [
        ('Shut Down Required', 'Shut Down Required'),
        ('Shut Down Not Required', 'Shut Down Not Required'),

        ]

    _columns = {
            'number' : fields.char('Calendar Inspection ID',readonly=1),
            'tags' : fields.selection(STATE_SELECTION, 'Tags',),
            'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users','res_users_rel','Assigned', track_visibility='onchange',),
            'sht_down': fields.boolean('Shut Down'),

            'company_id11': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
            #'place' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Substation Location',),



            'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',),
            'folio_num1' : fields.many2one('asset.asset','Folio Num',),

            'inspection_name' : fields.many2many('asset1.inspection','asset1_inspection_rel','super_id','asset1_inspection_id','Inspection Type'),

            'insp_rslt' : fields.one2many('feedback.tree','insp_rsltts','Inspection Result',),
            'same_as':fields.boolean(),

            }


    _defaults = {
                'number' : lambda self,cr,uid,context={}:self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr,uid,'calendar.event'),
                'sht_down': False,
                }
    def onchange_same_as(self,cr, uid, ids,same_as_above,inspec_type,context=None):
        if same_as:
            return {'value':{'shutdown':frequency,}}
        return {'value':{}}



class feedback_tree(osv.Model):
    _name = 'feedback.tree'

    STATUS = [
        ('done', 'Completed'),
        ('notdone', 'Not-Completed'),
    ]

    _columns = {

        'folionum' : fields.many2one('calendar.event','Task Name',),
        #'folio_number' : fields.many2one('asset.asset','Folio number',),
        'inspec_type' : fields.char('Inspection Type',),
        'insp_msr1' : fields.many2one('results.measure','Attributes',),
        'valuess' : fields.char('Values'),
        'status' : fields.selection(STATUS,'Status'),
        'insp_rsltts': fields.many2one('feedback.form','Result Id'),


    }
```

The follwoing code is .xml file for above inherited class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

    <!-- Form & Tree View for Visitor Register -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherit_calaner_event">
            <field name="name">calender.event.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//form/sheet/div[@class='oe_title']" position="after">
                    <group>
                       <!-- <field name="number"/>-->
            <field name="company_id11"/>

            <!--<field name="asset_catg_id"/>
            <field name="area_id" widget="selection"/>-->
            <field name="assetmodelid_add" />
            <field name="folio_num1" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/>
            <field name="inspection_name" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/>
            <field name="sht_down"/>
                    </group>

                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group/group/field[@name='location']" position="after">
                    <group>
                    </group>
                </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group/group/field[@name='categ_ids']" position="replace">
        <field name="tags"/></xpath>
        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/div/label[@string='Attendees']" position="replace">
         <label string="Attendees" class="oe_edit_only"/></xpath>
        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/div/h2" position="replace">
         <field name="user_id"/></xpath>
        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Meeting Details']" position="after">
            <page string="Feedback">
            <field name="insp_rslt" >
            <tree string="Feedback" editable="bottom" > 
            <field name="folionum" />

            <field name="insp_msr1"/>
            <field name="valuess"/>
            <field name="status"/></tree></field>
            </page>
        </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    <record id="calendar_view_calendar_event_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">calender.event.view</field>
        <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_search"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//search/filter[@name='message_unread']" position="after">
        <filter string="Shut Down" name="sht_down" domain="[('sht_down','=',True)]"/>
        <filter string="No Shut Down" name="sht_down" domain="[('sht_down','=',False)]"/></xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

My Requirement is First I will select `inspection_name` field in `calender.evnt` class. In `feedback.tree` I have one column `inspc_type` this field has to give only same list as many2one of `inspection_name` which assigned for this instance.

Example: `inspction_name` has A,B,C
in `feedback.tree` for inspec_type should get only A,B,C not all inspection_name which stored before this record.

-----------------Edited------------------------------

I have **calendar.event.py**

```
'inspection_name' : fields.many2many('asset1.inspection','asset1_inspection_rel','super_id','asset1_inspection_id','Inspection Type'),
```

.xml file of **calendar.event.py**

```
<field name="assetmodelid_add" />
            <field name="folio_num1" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/>
            <field name="inspection_name" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/>
```

I want same filter in `feedback.tree`. When I do domain filter its showing assetmodelid_add doesn't exist. ya because in `feedback.tree` we don't have this field so how to crack this

```
'inspec_type': fields.char('Inspection Type',),
```

field has to be done domain filter for this class  for **'inspec_type'**  field

Comment: Rather to give your requirement, it's better to edit your question with: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output or any track-back.

Comment: any one tell me answer

Comment: @ShridharIvani Can you more explain about problem? First of all. I see that `inspection_name` it its many2many field. `feedback.tree` can have relation with calendar event. You want show value `inspection_name`(from *calendar.event*) on form with `feedback.tree`?

Comment: I wanted domain filter for one2many field <field name="inspection_name" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/> This is in same class so its  working fine now i wante this field in feedbac.tree class . it has to work same as calendar.event works.domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/> how to add this filter in feedback.tree field for same field

Comment: @DanilaGanchar ya same operation i needed bro please help me to get out of this problem

Comment: @ShridharIvani as I understood, you want to limit the list for **folio_num1** using value from field **assetmodelid_add**. Is it right?

Comment: no its for inspection_name not for folio_num1  that field has to come in tree view like one2many bro how to do that

Comment: @DanilaGanchar help me bro

Comment: @ShridharIvani I can't understand))) You want something show in your `tree` for `feedback.tree` from `calendar.event` ?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Not something **inspection_name** only .If you send your skype or mail id we can see on live you will get it drop a mail shridharivani@gmail.com

Comment: @DanilaGanchar ** inspection_name** is in many2many r8 so i want same field in tree view i.e as many2one field . ... Now **inspection_name ** filtering  based on assetmodelid_add . so same ristrinction i want it in tree view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102663/discussion-between-shridhar-ivani-and-danila-ganchar).